# Set ViewModel in one fragment, and fetch the new data in other fragments in SingleActivity app with NavHost?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some trouble with a SingleActivity with a NavHost app in android. There is some text strings from EditText widgets in a fragment that I need to put into a ViewModel, and update the other fragments with the new ViewModel data. I do this from MainActivity in an OnClick method from a floating action button that I is outside the NavHost implementation.

So, I've tried

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

CreateFragment fragment = (CreateFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_create);
            fragment.saveInputFromTextFields();
```

But here findFragmentById returns null, and I don't know why.

I have a solution from a question I asked previously, that I use in MainActivity to find the current displayed fragment and calling a method from it;

```
Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        if (navHostFragment instanceof NavHostFragment) {
            Fragment visibleFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

            if (visibleFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                
                ((HomeFragment) visibleFragment).saveInputFromTextFields();
            }
        }
```

But this doesn't work after one use, because `navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);`  always returns the previous fragment, and changing `get(0)` to `get(1)` crashes the app with a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

What I really need is a reliable way of setting ViewModel data in one fragment and updating the other fragments with the new data.
I've heard of something called LiveData or DataBinding, do I need to implement something like this? It feels like overkill.
The data I'm working with is one array list in the ViewModel that contains items that fill a recycler view. I use the fragments for creating new items or editing current items, that I just need to get access to somehow. I feel like there is a simpler way, but I don't know how to implement this. Please tell me if you need more information from me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just to clarify, Fragment A is your current destination and you are trying to obtain a reference to Fragment B?

Comment: Hello Davidtagt, You are on the right track, using `shared VM + Live data` is the way to go . You can tie the VM scope to your SingleActivity. This way this VM will stay alive until your activity dies. Then, form the fragments, you can obtain the same VM. 

Then, whenever/wherever you get a new data, just post them to via the VM livedata, this will automatically notify any other fragments that's subscribed/observing this vm livedata.

This is just to keep you going for now, I can provide you some sample code later on when I get a chance if you need.

Comment: @HenryTwist Correct, in Fragment A i have a list of things, and I create a new Thing for the list in Fragment B. How do I get that newly created Thing to be in the list in Fragment A?

Comment: @Boda thank you very much for your reply. Do you have a link to a good tutorial I can follow along? I have no clue how to implement this, and the NavHost part only makes things harder

Comment: @Davidtagt the links provided by Henry seems good for me, it will help learn and implement what you need. Check them and if you have further questions reach out again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Navigation Components are intended to be used primarily for navigating between top level destinations. Therefore a `NavHostFragment` has a single destination that is currently active at any one time which explains why you can only retrieve the current fragment from its fragment manager.

If you're looking to share data between fragments I would looking into using a `ViewModel` scoped to your activity so that both your fragments can hold reference. There is some starter documentation here: [Share data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). There is also a codelab which will give you a head start into shared view models but also working with `LiveData` which I would definitely recommend: [Shared ViewModel Across Fragments Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0).

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was going about it the wrong way. The data I needed to update can be updated when the fragments are destroyed and created. So there's really no need for me to tell an instance of the fragment to update the data manually, as that can be handled by android.

Thank you all for your replies.